# How to play one audio right after another in flutter?

Tags: flutter, audio, just-audio

I have like 10 - 15 audio, and I need to play them one after another or you can say merge them. They are dynamic(I get the urls from server). I'm using the `just_audio` packege for playing audio. I'm using `ConcatenatingAudioSource` to play one audio after another

This is how I initialize the player

```
late AudioPlayer _audioPlayer;
  List<AudioPlayer> players = [];
  ConcatenatingAudioSource concatenatingAudioSource =
      ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: []);

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      final state = ref.watch(homeController);
      state.ayahList.forEach((element) async {
        final player = AudioPlayer();
        await player.setUrl('https://example.com/$element.mp3');
        players.add(player);
      });
      final audioSources = players
          .map((player) => player.audioSource ?? AudioSource.uri(Uri()))
          .toList();
      concatenatingAudioSource =
          ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: audioSources);
      _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer()..setAudioSource(concatenatingAudioSource);
    });
  }
```

This is the UI, it's very simple

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: audioPlayer.playerStateStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          final playerState = snapshot.data;
          final processingState = playerState?.processingState;
          final playing = playerState?.playing;
          if (!(playing ?? false)) {
            return IconButton(
                onPressed: () => audioPlayer.play(),
                icon: const Icon(Icons.play_arrow_rounded));
          } else if (processingState != ProcessingState.completed) {
            return IconButton(
                onPressed: () => audioPlayer.pause(),
                icon: const Icon(Icons.pause_rounded));
          }
          return const Icon(Icons.play_arrow_rounded);
        });
  }
```

Now when I click the play button, nothing happens, nothing on the log as well. Maybe I got the whole wrong idea about `concatenatingAudioSource`, I don't know. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out another way to play one audio after another

```
onPressed: () {
              audioPlayer.setUrl(
                  'https:example.com/${state.ayahList[i-1]}.mp3');
              audioPlayer.play();

              audioPlayer.playerStateStream.listen((event) async {
                if (event.processingState == ProcessingState.completed) {
                  if (i < state.ayahList.length) {
                    audioPlayer.setUrl(
                        'https://example.com/${state.ayahList[i]}.mp3');
                    await audioPlayer.play().then((value) => i++);

                  } else {
                    i = 0;
                  }
                }
              });
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because `ref.watch` is used during `initState`. This is not the place to put a watch as it will not be "watched".

At this point, if you're sure that `homeController` is well initialized and you don't want to re-trigger the code block within `addPostframeCallback`, you can use `ref.read` instead.

Otherwise you should define a function like `handleHomeControllerChanged`, listen to your `homeController` inside `build` method (you should change your `statefulWidget` to `consumerWidget` in order to be able to have access to ref.listen).  This way, you can listen to changes on `homeController` and re-trigger the function each time the controller changes.